Horror short story about a watchmaker who sits in his shop as various characters come in and out of the store
I listened to a horror short story on YouTube about 6 or 7 years ago, I've been trying to find it for a while. Since I listened to it on YouTube, I cannot tell you if it was by a published author or an amateur. I suspect it was probably taken from a magazine based, probably between the 60s and 90s, but it could have been earlier. The voice over artists were decent but not anyone recognisable. My memory is muddy, so don't take anything as gospel. I believe it was set in the early 19th century. The writing style resembled HP Lovecraft's work. I believe the prose focuses a lot on the terror of the main character.
It was about a watchmaker who sits in his shop as various characters come in and out of the store. At first comes in a man who is quite irate and he and mentions a plot point about the murder of a girl in the attic of some house in the town. Then one day, this weird guy come in and wants his watch repaired. This guy speaks differently to the other characters. I believe he is described to be dressed strangely, implying he is from another time or dimension.
It turns out that this watch that is is some kind of eldritch artifact, and the watchmaker ends up in the room of the girl who was murdered, but in some alternate time or universe. I believe there is some strange thing that happens to the room, like the walls close in, or turn to blood, or something like that.
The strange man never comes back to collect his watch. The watchmaker puts it deep in a drawer.
The video was maybe 25 or 35 minutes, perhaps a little longer. The video was a still image of an eldritch-looking eye and a clock face superimposed. It had very few views and comments at the time I watched it. I can't for the life of me find this story. Does this plot sound familiar to anyone?

Search your YouTube Watch History and you should be able to find it.

I don't have that saved. I'm hoping someone is familiar with this story.
